# Linux/Debian equivalent of macOS's date -jf, set source date format?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date, debian

I have a date in the format of `201908270700` but need to change it to `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm`, when googling I find lots of solutions to do this with the macOS command line, but not many for linux, at least not a simple solution.

On macOS you can do `date -jf "%Y%m%d%H%M" "201908270700" "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M"` and it'll return `2019/08/27 07:00`, but looking at the GNU date man page, there is no equivalent option on Linux, or is there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the date in a variable, it's easy to format into a form the GNU coreutils `date(1)` understands:

```sh
$ dt=201908270700
$ date -d"${dt:0:8} ${dt:8:4}" "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M"
2019/08/27 07:00
```

This splits the date and time up into separate elements, which can then be parsed according to the rules for [pure numbers](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Pure-numbers-in-date-strings.html#Pure-numbers-in-date-strings) in the coreutils documentation.